# What is the M-point of an orthorhombic crystal structure?

Tags: quantum-espresso, k-points

In [this paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/aenm.202001305), they have plotted the band structure of orthorhombic  $\ce{CsPbI3}$ using Wein2k. The k-path given here is Γ—X—R—Z—Γ—X—R—A—M—X, but I cannot find the M point in the orthorhombic crystal structure [online](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brillouin_zone).

**What is the M point of an orthorhombic crystal structure? What are the coordinates?**

This question has reference to my  [previous post](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/6660/how-to-implement-discontinuous-k-points-in-quantum-espresso) on the Brilloiun zone k-path.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but instead the description of a resource that you can use to learn about high symmetry points and paths of *any* structure (including your orthorhombic lead halide perovskite).

Website: [SeeK-path](https://www.materialscloud.org/work/tools/seekpath)

Short description: it allows you to upload a crystal structure (in many formats, including QE, VASP, CASTEP, cif), and it depicts the Brillouin zone, high symmetry coordinates and labels, and provides a suggested high symmetry path along the Brillouin zone on which to evaluate the band structure.

For you: if you upload your structure file (I understand you have it in QE format?), then it should provide the coordinates of the M point.

Comment: Thank you for your response @ProfM but Seek-path is not showing the M point as a high symmetry point of an orthorhombic crystal structure. However, this paper : https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jallcom.2020.158442 and the one I mentioned in my post have used "M" as one of the high symmetry points.

Comment: Is it possible that there is no M point in such an orthorhombic structure, and these papers are incorrect? I know the point (1/2,1/2,0) is the M point in a cubic system, but not sure about orthorhombic...

Comment: From browsing the paper in the question, I guess there is some attempt at keeping the path uniform over multiple perovskite structures? So points may be labeled without being high-symmetry points? It'd really help if they had drawn the Brillouin zone and path somewhere.